# Application Folder for Box.net

Tags: box-api

For dropbox, we use an "application folder" where docs are placed for our application. When authenticated, we only see files for that folder. What is the equivalent with Box.net?

Looking at the (Java) API, it seems that the only choice is to look through all the files on their drive.

Comment: FWIW, we only read from this folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Provision Grant workflow](https://developers.box.com/provision/). Given an email address Box will add a sandboxed application folder to the user's account, creating the account as necessary.

Comment: That looks pretty close. I don't actually want to create a new Box.net account for the user though. Is there a web-flow to get this permission / folder creation?

Comment: does this mean the java api .getRootFolder would return the appropriate folder?

Comment: "When authenticated, we only see files for that folder." If you don't want the user to have an account, where do you propose that this folder should go?

Comment: marking answer as correct as it does seem like the right way to go, but seems like lots of details left to be asked regarding how it really works.

Answer (score 0):

John's answer is correct that [Provision Grant](https://developers.box.com/provision/) is the way to go about doing this. As for the Java SDK, it unfortunately doesn't support the provisioning auth workflow yet (this is a feature we're looking to add).

However, if you are able to do provisioning authentication manually, you can hand off your access/refresh tokens to the SDK and then use it normally.

```
BoxAPIConnection api = new BoxAPIConnection("clientID", "clientSecret",
    "accessToken", "refreshToken");

// You can also set the expiration time if you want the SDK to auto-
// refresh your access token for you.
api.setExpires(expires); 

// Your application's folder will be returned after you authenticate
// with provision grant.
String appFolderID = "id";

BoxFolder appFolder = new BoxFolder(api, appFolderID);
for (BoxItem.Info itemInfo : appFolder) {
    // Do something with the items in your app's folder.
}
```

Apologies that this isn't very intuitive. I created [an issue](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/issues/75) for adding better provision grant support to the SDK.

Comment: So what I'm thinking is the following, let me know if this makes sense.

1) Forward user to Box's authorization page. This is to ensure they are selecting the appropriate Box account they've already created. This should give us access to their whole Box account(?) and email?

2) We call the grant provision for the email in step 1, then toss the original
tokens, and use the grant provision tokens. This will give us access to just one folder on their account, and they will have us mapped to the account they expect (not some new mistyped email address account).

Will this work appropriately?

Comment: I did something like what you have above. Oddly when listening to events it  sends ones outside the granted app folder. Also, I can't figure out how to get events for all users' granted app folder (you can't seem to authenticate as the app in Java).

Comment: You shouldn't need to have the user log into their Box account. If you have provision grant enabled for your app, then you should be able to provision a folder by just asking the user for their email (a password shouldn't be required). The access token you get back will limit your access to only that provisioned folder. The Java SDK doesn't support provisioning auth yet, so you will need to do the auth flow yourself. However, once you have manually authenticated, you can give the tokens to the SDK so it can handle token refresh, rate-limiting, JSON parsing, and other things for you.